# Nesting an array of structure into another structure

Tags: c, arrays, nested, structure

I am trying to create a structure that includes an array of structures.

my code this far (cut to only two glyphs)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct glyph_t{
        uint16_t width;
        uint16_t length;
        uint16_t *data;
} glyph_t;

typedef struct font_t{
    uint8_t height;
    glyph_t glyphs[2];
} font_t;


// '9' character
const uint16_t glyph_0_data[] = {
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xc318,0xef7b,0x79ce,0x7def,0xbef7,0xfbde,0x34a5,0x2842,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x2842,0x7def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xf39c,0x2000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x6529,0xbef7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9294,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x18c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xe739,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0xc739,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x34a5,0x0421,0x6108,0x8a52,0x5def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x96b5,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x718c,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x79ce,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0842,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xdfff,0x8210,0x0000,
    0x0000,0xbad6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x4d6b,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x59ce,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xaa52,0x0000,
    0x2000,0xdfff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6529,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xef7b,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x518c,0x0000,
    0x2421,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x2000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x694a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xb6b5,0x0000,
    0xa631,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8631,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xdbde,0x0000,
    0xe739,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x5def,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xe318,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xbef7,0x0000,
    0xe739,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xc318,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x4108,
    0x6529,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x2000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8210,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa210,
    0x8210,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6529,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4108,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xe318,
    0x0000,0x3ce7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xcf7b,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x6108,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x0421,
    0x0000,0x34a5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x5def,0xc318,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8210,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xc318,
    0x0000,0x494a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xdbde,0x694a,0x6108,0x6108,0x0842,0x75ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6108,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x59ce,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x8631,0x9ef7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0842,0x5def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x59ce,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xa210,0x1084,0x9ad6,0x9ef7,0x9ef7,0xbad6,0x9294,0x55ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x34a5,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x75ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xef7b,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x1ce7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x0842,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8631,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x2000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x718c,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x75ad,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xc318,0xbef7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x694a,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x75ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ad6,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x718c,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xcb5a,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x2421,0xd7bd,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xf7bd,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x6108,0x8631,0x4d6b,0xb6b5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x3ce7,0xe318,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x38c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x5def,0x8631,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x55ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ad6,0x2421,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x718c,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x7def,0xcf7b,0x2000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x8e73,0x5def,0x79ce,0xf39c,0xaa52,0x4108,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000 }; //glyph_0_data

glyph_t glyph_0 = {
    .width = 17,
    .length = 782,
    .data = glyph_0_data
};


// 'A' character
const uint16_t glyph_1_data[] = {
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xeb5a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x3084,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xb6b5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xdbde,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8210,0xdfff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6529,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xeb5a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x1084,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x96b5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xbad6,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4108,0xbef7,0xffff,0xffff,0x79ce,0x9ad6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x2421,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xaa52,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x1084,0x1084,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xae73,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x14a5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x8631,0x8631,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x18c6,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x7def,0xffff,0xffff,0x1ce7,0x0000,0x0000,0x1ce7,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x8210,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xc739,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xb294,0x0000,0x0000,0xd39c,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xcb5a,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x3084,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x694a,0x0000,0x0000,0x8a52,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x34a5,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x79ce,0xffff,0xffff,0xdfff,0x6108,0x0000,0x0000,0x6108,0xdfff,0xffff,0xffff,0x7def,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xa210,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xf7bd,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x18c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa631,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xeb5a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xcf7b,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x1084,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xef7b,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x14a5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xc739,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0842,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x18c6,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x3ce7,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x2000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4108,0xdfff,0xffff,0xffff,0xdfff,0x6108,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4529,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xb6b5,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x18c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x494a,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x6d6b,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xae73,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x1084,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x718c,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x96b5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa631,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0842,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ad6,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x9ef7,0xffff,0xffff,0x9ef7,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4108,0xdfff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x8210,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8631,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xb6b5,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x18c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x8a52,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x8e73,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x9294,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x96b5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x79ce,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x7def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6108,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x6529,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x55ad,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x75ad,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x494a,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x4d6b,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xcf7b,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xef7b,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x3084,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x34a5,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x494a,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x694a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xf7bd,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0xfbde,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa210,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xe318,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xbef7,0x2000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0xc318,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x3ce7,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x7def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa631,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x694a,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xd7bd,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x18c6,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x6d6b,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x3084,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x718c,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xb294,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x34a5,0x0000,
    0x0000,0xd7bd,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0x2c63,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x4d6b,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xfbde,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x7def,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xc739,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0xc739,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xffff,0xa210,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,
    0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000,0x0000
}; //glyph_1_data

glyph_t glyph_1 = {
    .width = 24,
    .length = 1104,
    .data = glyph_1_data
};

font_t font = {
    .height = 48, 
    .glyphs[] = {glyph_0, glyph_1}
};

int main()
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d\n", font.height);
    printf("%d\n", font.glyph[0].width);
    printf("%d\n",font.glyph[0].data[106]);
    printf("%d\n", font.glyph[1].width);
    printf("%d\n",font.glyph[1].data[106]);
}
```

When compiling, I got the following error:

```
font2.c:133:2: error: array index in initializer exceeds array bounds
  .glyphs[2] = {glyph_0, glyph_1}
  ^
font2.c:133:2: error: (near initialization for ‘font.glyphs’)
font2.c:133:2: error: initializer element is not constant
font2.c:133:2: error: (near initialization for ‘font.glyphs[0].width’)
font2.c:133:2: error: initializer element is not constant
font2.c:133:2: error: (near initialization for ‘font.glyphs[0].length’)
```

I also tried:

```
font_t font;
font.height = 48;
font.glyphs[0] = glyph_0;
font.glyphs[1] = glyph_1;
```

When compiling I get this following error:

```
 gcc -o test font2.c 
font2.c:132:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 font.height = 48;
     ^
font2.c:133:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 font.glyphs[0] = glyph_0;
     ^
font2.c:134:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 font.glyphs[1] = glyph_1;
```

I also tried various combinations of `"glyphs[2]"` and `"glyphs[]"` with no success. I have no idea what either error means. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove `[]` from the line 133

Comment: Yep, it's just `.glyphs = { ... }`, where ... can contain either the names of previously initialized glyph structures, or new ones in {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other answer explains the syntax and semantic problems in your approach; please do not accept this one over that.  I simply want to add that you *can* perform the initialization at file scope, as long as you are willing to use literals.  That seems reasonable to me, as I don't see why you want to duplicate your glyph data as your original code attempts to do.  It might look like this:

```
font_t font = {
    .height = 48, 
    .glyphs = {
        { .width = 17, .length = 782,  .data = glyph_0_data },
        { .width = 24, .length = 1104, .data = glyph_1_data }
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm surprised this compiled.  Is it because `glyph_0_data` decays to a pointer?

Comment: Yes, @dbush.  More precisely, because it decays to a pointer to a visible, file-scope variable.  The pointer's value is effectively a compile-time constant.  This is not unlike initializing a `char *` with a string literal.

Comment: While @dbush's clue of "field glyphs is already known to be an array, so no need for the subscript operator" root cause, merely dropping the "[]" did not complile. John Bollinger's answer compiled and yielded the needed binary. I am inclined to mark this as the answer. Is there a way to give partial credit to another person?

Answer (score 1):

You're using invalid syntax when initializing `font`:

```
font_t font = {
    .height = 48, 
    .glyphs[] = {glyph_0, glyph_1}
    //     ^^ ---- here
};
```

The field `glyphs` is already known to be an array, so no need for the subscript operator.

However, even if you did this there would still be an error because `font` is defined a file scope and the values you're using for initialization contain other variables names instead of constants.

The syntax of assigning each field is valid, but only within a function.  An assignment is an executable statement, and those can't exist outside of a function.

Define the variable at file scope without initializing, then set the field in `main`:

```
font_t font;

int main()
{
    font.height = 48;
    font.glyphs[0] = glyph_0;
    font.glyphs[1] = glyph_1;

    printf("\n");
    ...
```

Comment: I think you're confusing him. Named initializers are fine at file scope. There's no need for assignment statements.

Comment: Yes, @LeeDanielCrocker, designated initializers are fine at file scope, but the *values* in file-scope initializers, designated or not, cannot be expressed as the values of variables.  That's the reason for suggesting initialization via a function.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The named initializers are fine.  The problem is that `glyph_0` and `glyph_1` can't be used to initialize at file scope because they aren't constants.

Comment: Ah, right, I was thinking I'd done something like this before, but my array was probably of pointers rather than included whole structures.